# How to search for a value that isnt as item in a v-autocomplete

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a v-autocomplete:

```
    <v-autocomplete
              v-model="fromPrice"
              :items="listOfFromItems"
              dense
              solo
              label="from"
              hide-details
              return-object
              color="red darken-1"
            />
```

I have populated with a list like this:

```
for (let i = 0; i <= 5000; i += 50) {
  this.listOfFromItems = [...this.listOfFromItems, i];
}

 [0, 50, 100, 150.......5000]
```

I want to make something like that, when I write a number (for example 12) which in not in the array, the value of v-autocomplete will be the written number, 12.
Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The component you're looking for is called [Combobox](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/combobox/).